# надо написать функцию если не строка то надо сложить

Tags: javascript

```js
let salaries = {
  user1: 20000,
  name: 'Test'
  user2: 30000,
  surName: 'Test',
  user3: 40000,
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let salaries = {
  user1: 20000,
  name: 'Test',
  user2: 30000,
  surName: 'Test',
  user3: 40000,
}
console.log(
  Object.values(salaries)
  .filter((v) => typeof v === 'number')
  .reduce((a, v) => a += v, 0)
)
```

Comment: a другой вариант?

Comment: @AramGasparyan А чем этот вариант не устроил?

Comment: спасибо все супер